# Error while performing registry transaction operation

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Getting this error:

> Error while performing registry transaction operation

when trying to edit an api group. The group was working correctly before.

Comment: Did you check whether the user who edit the API group has the necessary permissions to do it ? And what is the version of API Manager you are using ?

Comment: I am editing as admin and I am using Identity server 5.2.0 and api manager 2.0.0

Comment: I doulbt whether you have an issue in registry mounting. Can you make sure following. 1. Has not removed existing dbConfig for WSO2CarbonDB in registry.xml, 2. Has correctly added the registry mounts. 3. clear out the registry path /_system/local/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.registry/mount once, restart and try to recreate the issue.